# Visual Studio CATIA Product Creation

Tags: visual-studio-2017, catia

I am trying to create a product using visual studio in CATIA. I have imported all the required references like INFITF MECMOD ProductStructureTypeLib. I have written a small code to create a product. It is working fine according to the code but instead of creating product. it is asking me to enter product name in catia window.

Code written so far.

```
Dim documents1 as documents
documents1=catiafile.documents

Dim productdocument1 as productdocument
productdocument1=documents1.add("Product")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by a CATIA setting. If the setting is activated then users are prompted to enter a document name whenever a new document is created.

To disable the setting:

1. Launch CATIA.
2. Open the settings window by Tools > Options.
3. In the settings tree on the left select Infrastructure > Product Structure
4. In the right part of the settings window switch to the tab Product Structure.
5. Disable the option Part Number > Manual Input.
6. Close the settings window with OK.

Comment: This is correct. Unfortunately this is one of those settings which you cannot check the value of or change the setting in your code as you run. 

In our environment, we all users have the ability to change this setting. 

So because I cannot be sure what the setting will be when the application is run, I  copy and rename an empty Product file then open that instead of using Documents.Add